# Textcell Displays on Simulator but not Android

Tags: android, android-layout, xamarin.forms, background-color

I am having issues with my xaml displaying correctly in the Simulator but not when packaged and installed on my Android Phone. Also just normal Labels in the stack layout do not show up at all on my phone, they are probably white!
And about the app Performance on my Phone, it functions as in the simulator the buttons are also at the same spot as in the simulator but not visible.
I am Testing with the Pixel 5 and have tested Oneplus 5 on the Simulator and my Phone is a Oneplus 5T.

As you can see in the pictures the text displays correctly but the Detail does not show up?
I am new to programming and do not know if this is a issue with my style not being defined... or which colors would change the text or even the background.

[Screenshots of the app on my phone and the simulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nX6dR.jpg)

Code:

Settings Page

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="Bottom_Tab.Views.SettingsPage"
             Title="Settings">

    <ContentPage.Content>
        <TableView  Intent="Settings">
            <TableRoot>
                <TableSection Title="Settings">
                    <TextCell Text="Language" Detail="" TextColor="Black" />
                </TableSection>
                <TableSection Title="User">
                    <TextCell Text="Login"  TextColor="Black" Tapped="Login_Tapped"/>
                    <TextCell Text="Logout"  TextColor="Black" Tapped="Logout_Tapped"/>
                    <TextCell Text="UserName" Detail="Change Username" TextColor="Black" />
                </TableSection>
                <TableSection Title="Other">
                    <TextCell Text="Version" Detail="a23w49b" TextColor="Black" />
                    <TextCell Text="Credits" TextColor="Black" Tapped="Credits_Tapped" />
                </TableSection>
            </TableRoot>
        </TableView>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

Sytles.xaml in "Project.Android"

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<resources>

  <style name="MainTheme" parent="MainTheme.Base">
    <!-- As of Xamarin.Forms 4.6 the theme has moved into the Forms binary -->
    <!-- If you want to override anything you can do that here. -->
    <!-- Underneath are a couple of entries to get you started. -->

    <!-- Set theme colors from https://aka.ms/material-colors -->
    <!-- colorPrimary is used for the default action bar background -->
    <!--<item name="colorPrimary">#2196F3</item>-->..
    <!-- colorPrimaryDark is used for the status bar -->
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#00FF96</item>
    <!-- colorAccent is used as the default value for colorControlActivated
         which is used to tint widgets -->
    <item name="colorAccent">#ff006a</item>

  </style>
</resources>
```

colors.xaml in "Project.Android"

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="launcher_background">#FFFFFF</color>
    <color name="colorPrimary">#3F51B5</color>
    <color name="colorPrimaryDark">#303F9F</color>
    <color name="colorAccent">#FF4081</color>
</resources>
```

---

Also I did not change the apk name and the SDK versions are from android 5-13 and my phone has android 9. So that should not be a problem.

I tried changing the launcher Background in colors.xaml from white to grey, to see if the text on my phone is actally just whit eon white!
And serched the interent for answers but did not find anything.

```
<color name="launcher_background">#888888</color>
```

But the backgroundcolor did not change.

Comment: Try to run the app via debug mode on your phone, see if it will display well.  In addition, check this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/deploy-test/release-prep/?tabs=windows#configure-the-linker)(Configure the Linker), it could cause some helpful assemblies to be ignored when in release mode.

Comment: @JianweiSun-MSFT
Thank you for your comment. I did not kno₩about these features you mentioned.
Firstly the phone debugging is very usefull and I realised that the release Version works on my Huawei but not OnePlus. And debugging both Phones results in a wierd error.
"**System.MissingMethodException:** 'Default constructor not found for type LEAVR.Views.ScreentimePage'"

Also I checked and the Linker is configured to None so that can't be the problem.

The only Idea I have is to define the colors for everything in my code and not let it up to the style to decide.

Comment: NVM my comment above I figure out, that i had left the Linker settings on "Sdk and User Assemblies" but when set back to "None" Debug mode works again.
Just on my one phone the text is still missing.

Comment: You mean the text is still missing when the Linker setting is "None" and release Version for OnePlus? Huawei works well but not for OnePlus?

Comment: @JianweiSun-MSFT
Yes, exactly.

I was messing with the code and figured out, that probably the only reason It shows the text in settings, is that I set the "Textcolor" to black but not the "Detailcolor"
*(I Tested this and now the details show up!)

So I think it must be that my phone has a different theme or something and it would be best practice to define all coclors in the "APPshell.xaml"

Comment: Great! But to be honest, this design is a bit speechless... I make an answer according to your comment.

Answer (score 0):

For Detail of TextCell, it is best to use "`DetailColor`" to modify:

[image]

Comment: This should have been XAML text, not an image.